# XSLT test for text or everything

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

I'm merging two files, a WADL file and an XML file containing DITA fragments to ultimately generate a DITA file. the DITA fragments can be a string of text or a block of DITA tags. trying to determine if an element in the DITA fragments file is populated (or even exists) with the following test:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="docIDtext" select="$docId//doc[@id=$resourcepath]/*|text()"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$docIDtext">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$docIDtext"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <draft-comment author="doc">FIXME: missing DocID</draft-comment>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

however, the test for `$docIDtext` is always true, which is not the correct result. it's that pesky "*". How can I do this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell without input documents and the expected output, but I guess the fix is to write:

```
<xsl:variable name="docIDtext" select="
    $docId//doc[@id=$resourcepath]/* |
    $docId//doc[@id=$resourcepath]/text()
"/>
```

An expression of the form `a/b|c` is evaluated as `(a/b) | c`, not `a/(b|c)`, the latter being invalid in XPath 1.0 anyway.

The `xsl:variable` instruction above could be optimized by using a temporary value for the `doc` element. But the best solution might be to use the `node()` node test which will match any type of child node:

```
<xsl:variable name="docIDtext" select="$docId//doc[@id=$resourcepath]/node()"/>
```

This will return both child elements and text nodes (but also comments and processing instructions).

Comment: that unfortunately misses the question. the statement `<xsl:copy-of select="$docId//doc[@id=$resourcepath]/*|text()"/>` works as expected as does the variable shown in my question. the problem is i want to test the variable to see if it has content but the test for `docIDtext` appears to always return true.

Comment: responding to your answer made me realise i was missing an easier solution: just test for the presence of `$docId//doc[@id=$resourcepath]`. that way i don't have to care what the contents of the tag are, or even if it has contents, just if it exists. for my particular usecase, that's enough. thanks for the response and the trigger.

Comment: It depends on the context of your XSLT fragment, but also your `copy-of` instruction most certainly works not like you expect for text nodes of the `doc` element for the reason given in my answer.

Comment: it does work as required but you're probably correct that it's wrong. it's never been fed a text string but always some block of DITA tags so the asterisk matches rather than the `text()`. btw: i'm going to tag your response as answering my question, so thanks again.